# How to set up GeoDjango with PostGIS 2.0?

Tags: postgis, postgis-2.0, geodjango

I would like to run GeoDjango (Django 1.4) with Postgis 2.0.

Whenever I try to run `syncdb` I get the following error for geographic fields:

```
Failed to install index for stores.Store model: 
operator class "gist_geometry_ops" does not exist for access method "gist"
```

I have found various online discussions about this, but no clear answers.

It sounds as though I need to [create some indexes by hand](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-users/eb9eQNme1z0)... or perhaps there is a [patch that can help](https://github.com/django/django/pull/249), but I don't know how to add it.

Please could someone explain simply how to fix this error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GeoDjango 1.4 supports PostGIS 2.0 with too many workarounds to make it worth it.

Instead, install [GeoDjango 1.5 beta which natively supports PostGIS 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5-beta-1/) and switch to the [official release next month](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-developers/4EvlunsJ0LY).